# C++ limit of lines in #if - #endif?

Tags: c++, if-statement

A strange question passed throuh my mind today - is there a maximum count of the lines that can be placed in a #if...#endif code fragment?

I have a #if on the first line and then on the line 500 it suddenly closes without #endif. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "suddenly closes"?

Comment: No, no, there's no limit.

Comment: I think perhaps you are referring to the auto-indentation of your IDE and it is not automatically pairing after 500 lines?

Comment: @Moo-Juice No, I'm referring to the thin grey lines going down on the left side of the text and showing where different kinds of structures are closed :/ I made a little experiment - I put a #endif on this line, then opened a new #if and the same thing happened on line 1000 :/

Comment: It sounds weird to me myself, but I can't find any logical explaination :/ AND when I click the +/- label in front of the #if to hide it's structure, it continues from 500. That's why I think it's somehow closed on this line. There's no #endif or anything else that could close it.

Comment: It sounds like this is an issue with your editor. Which editor are you using?

Comment: @Moberg Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I'm talking about a header which is 2101 lines big.

Comment: Something more - I have dependency problems with exactly this header :/

Comment: Hm, I found a misplaced #endif, but it on 2052

Comment: OK, the problem was completely different... It's kind of solved now. I'll continue with that on Monday.

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit.

`#if .. #endif` pairs routinely cover the entirety of header files, and with std headers, some of those are huge.